# Convert discontinouo angle in continuos angle

Tags: matlab, trigonometry, angle

I am a new user and I need help to resolve a maltlab problem.
I have a matrix with angles and they have a range -180/180, but I have a problem when I want to show the graphic.
How I have a discontinuous angle, the representation is not like I want, so, someone knows how to convert this to continuous angles?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SE. It is totally unclear to me what you're trying to do. How are the angles arranged in the matrix, and what are you trying to plot?

Comment: I think that the problem is trying to plot the data from the matrix (or more likely a vector) and observing jumps/discontinuities when consecutive points straddle 180 (or -180) degrees.  The y-axis probably has a range of [-180,180] and you can imagine what happens when i=179, and i+1=-179.  Suggest plotting the data in batches where no points in the batch straddle 180 (or -180).

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your help.
ysap: I need the plot because I need to see the peaks and if I have a discontinuous line, sometimes I do not see the real peak, understand me?

Geoff, I agree with you, but I have not I need analyse the datas in matrix.

The example is correct, but I have not to calculate the frequency and other parameters?

Sorry about my questions.
Thanks.
Best wishes
Paulo Oliveira

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [`unwrap`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html):

Example:

```
>> phase = 5:.5:8 %// original phase. Exceeds 2*pi
phase =
    5.0000    5.5000    6.0000    6.5000    7.0000    7.5000    8.0000
>> phase_disc = mod(phase,2*pi) %// phase with discontinuity
phase_disc =
    5.0000    5.5000    6.0000    0.2168    0.7168    1.2168    1.7168
>> unwrap(phase_disc) %// recover original phase by removing discontinuity
ans =
    5.0000    5.5000    6.0000    6.5000    7.0000    7.5000    8.0000
```

Note that `unwrap` works in radians, not in degrees.